# Nullable field is changed upon writing a Spark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The following code reads a Spark DataFrame from parquet file and writes to another parquet file. Nullable filed in ArrayType DataType is changed after writing the DataFrame to a new Parquet file.

Code:

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
    String master = "local[2]";
    sparkConf.setMaster(master);
    sparkConf.setAppName("Local Spark Test");
    JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkContext(sparkConf));
    SQLContext sqc = new SQLContext(sparkContext);
    DataFrame dataFrame = sqc.read().parquet("src/test/resources/users.parquet");
    StructField[] fields = dataFrame.schema().fields();
    System.out.println(fields[2].dataType());
    dataFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("src/test/resources/users1.parquet");


    DataFrame dataFrame1 = sqc.read().parquet("src/test/resources/users1.parquet");
    StructField [] fields1 = dataFrame1.schema().fields();
    System.out.println(fields1[2].dataType());
```

Output:

```
ArrayType(IntegerType,false)
ArrayType(IntegerType,true)
```

Spark version is: 1.6.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Spark 2.4 or before, all the columns written from spark sql are nullable. Quoting [the official guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-data-sources-parquet.html)

> Parquet is a columnar format that is supported by many other data processing systems. Spark SQL provides support for both reading and writing Parquet files that automatically preserves the schema of the original data. When writing Parquet files, all columns are automatically converted to be nullable for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Is there any strong reason for it? As in what are those compatibility issues if the columns are not automatically converted to nullable?

Comment: I don't really know the answer. But I think it associates with how to output the Dataframe.

Comment: is it possible to disable this conversion?