# Dataframe schema is different from manually defined schema (textbook example)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Am just following the example in *Spark - The Definitive Guide* (chapter 5):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, LongType

myManualSchema = StructType([
    StructField('DEST_COUNTRY_NAME', StringType(), True),
    StructField('ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME', StringType(), True),
    StructField('count', LongType(), False, metadata={'hello': 'world'})])

df = spark.read.format('json').schema(myManualSchema).load('/data/flight-data/json/2015-summary.json')
```

But when I print the schema, it shows that `count` is still nullable. Any reason why? I am using PySpark (Spark 2.4.5) in Zeppelin docker 0.8.1.

```
print(myManualSchema)
print(df.schema)

>>> StructType(List(StructField(DEST_COUNTRY_NAME,StringType,true),StructField(ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME,StringType,true),StructField(count,LongType,false)))
>>> StructType(List(StructField(DEST_COUNTRY_NAME,StringType,true),StructField(ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME,StringType,true),StructField(count,LongType,true)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply the way Spark works, when coming from a *file source*.

It's a built in feature that allows things not to fail at run-time. A sort of safety valve.

If you google, you will find Q&A stating the same I am sure.

If you do it from some trivial own dataframe example using `val df = Seq(...)`, then this may not occur.

Has nothing to do with pyspark, just a Spark generic aspect. Text books can also be wrong or the APIs are subject to change.

Comment: Thanks. Though from 10 mins of searching, couldn't find Q&A for JSON file nullable fail-safe specifically. Only Parquet: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/sql-data-sources-parquet.html  (Referenced: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39697193/nullable-field-is-changed-upon-writing-a-spark-dataframe)